# PDO fetch method alters the pdo object itself

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

switching from mysql to PDO i noted that the fetch method alters the PDO object itself!
For exemple:

```
$res=$ps->fetchAll();
echo($res[0]['Mail']); //it'ok

//now i re-call the fetch method
$res=$ps->fetchAll();
echo($res[0]['Mail']); //no result!
```

Why happen this? In mysql i never seen this thing

Comment: why do you recall the fetch method?

Comment: Have you ever tried to `mysql_fetch_assoc` beyond the end of the result set...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object still contains your data, but it maintains an internal pointer to the current record. Every time you fetch a record from the result set, the pointer advances to the next row.

In the case of `fetchAll()`, the pointer has advanced to the end of the result set, so subsequent `fetchAll()` calls return no results.

If you need to call `fetchAll()` again, you can rewind the pointer to the beginning of the result set. This can be accomplished on buffered queries:

```
$ps->setAttribute(PDO_MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, 1);
$ps->rewind();
$ps->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` returns all remaining/available rows and if no more rows are available it will return `FALSE`; and `fetchAll` will return all available rows in single attempt and following calls will return `FALSE`, as no more data left in the result set.

We can reuse the array `$res` in your example above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware of what `fetch*` does:
When you fire off a query from PDO to the database, the database filters its data to put together a *result set* of the data you asked for. This will likely involve reading data from the harddisk, putting it into memory and keeping it there for some time. For large result sets, these are significant resources being spent. When you `fetch()` from PDO, one single result is copied over from the database's internal buffer to PHP's/PDO's internal buffer and returned to you as an array of data. When you call `fetch()` again, you get the next result and so on.

Once a result has be fetched, the database can free up that memory. The client (you) got the data it asked for, so the database can remove it from its memory. You cannot `fetch()` the same data again; for efficiency reasons.

`fetchAll()` fetches all results in one go and returns one big array. This is the same as:

```
$result = array();
while ($row = $pdo->fetch()) {
    $result[] = $row;
}
```

You cannot do the above again either.

In `mysql`, that's the same as this:

```
$result = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultSet)) {
    $result[] = $row;
}
```

You can't do that again either.

---

You *can* rewind the result set pointer in the database to explicitly tell it to read again what it already read, but this can be pretty inefficient and should be avoided. To keep your application performing fast, you should only transfer as little data back and forth as necessary and store as little data in memory at once as possible.

Comment: So you're saying that is better to use less fetch possibile?

Comment: You should indeed not fetch the same data more than once, because each fetch puts a load on the database server and may be orders of magnitude slower than reading the data PHP has already read before.

Comment: Not necessarily. `fetchAll` stores all results in memory at once. If you have just a few small results, that's not a big deal. But if you have many large results, you should not store them all in memory at once. Instead, loop through the results `fetch`ing one at a time, output it and then throw it away. What you should certainly *not* do is call `fetchAll` twice.